# Sticky footer that extends when at website-bottom and scrolling further

Tags: html, css

I had a very nice idea to make my project much prettier.
I want that the footer is standard like in the picture below:
[image: Website Picture]

And when i scroll further down now, that the footer goes up and bellow it is all the stuff like the "Impressum" and "Contact".
I searched the Internet for various solutions but couldn't find something fitting.
I hope you can help me.

Code of my footer:

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
            <p class="footer-text"><a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">OneClick</a></p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #F28724;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.footer-text {
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.footer-text > a {
    color: #3a3a3a;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Where's the picture?

Comment: that would be great to have a full HTML code or a https://jsfiddle.net/ example

Comment: unfortunately i use symfony for my project and thats rather not possible to put that working into a jsfiddle, and what i posted here should be more then enough to show my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.footerContent').slideDown(650);
    } else if ($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
      $('.footerContent').fadeOut(500);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 1000px;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #F28724;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.footer-text {
  color: #3a3a3a;
}
.footer-text > a {
  color: #3a3a3a;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.footerContent {
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #F28724;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="footer">
  <p class="footer-text"><a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">OneClick</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="footerContent">
  <p>Contact ...
    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: thx, it works like a charm at first glance, but it got some bugs when you scroll around a bit, maybe I'm able to fix them, not too sure about it, i will try

Comment: Play around a bit, let me know!

Comment: @BenjaminPössenberger - I just optimized my code & changed it a bit.

Comment: I figured out that it doesnt work on most of my sites and I'm not able to fix the Bugs it has on my site, its still a very good solution and i hope it helps other people :D

Comment: The change made it more beautiful, but now it works on even less sites, i have to go with a different style to put my Impressum / Contact

Comment: Oh, should I undo my changes?

Comment: no don't, this solution had since the start a problem with my site, so how it is now is more beautiful for other people, but thx for the effort :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try this solution that uses the `calc` function of CSS (read more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp), however, this is reported not supporting the IE8, I believe Chrome will run it well

HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <content>
    <p>content</p>
  </content>

  <footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
  </footer>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-height:100vh;
}

header {
    background: LightSlateGray;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
 header h1 { margin: 0; }

main { height: auto; min-height: calc(100vh - 100px); }
content, footer { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }

content { height: auto; min-height: calc(100vh - 200px); background:lightblue; }
footer {
    height:100px;           /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/89ucrec5/4/

Answer (score 0):

assign absolute position to footer and bottom:0;

Comment: the footer should stay a sticky footer, so when the content of the page is too much and i have to scroll. the footer is the small one in the picture all the time, when i reach the bottom of the page the footer scrolls further and the impressum stuff shows

PS: If it would have been such an easy fix i would just have figured it out my self

Comment: it should be a comment

Comment: Inzimam, I'm afraid i dont know what you want to say with your statement